# Doctrine 2 / MySQL: having trouble turning SQL left joins to DQL left joins

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm

So, the goal of my SQL is to get Apartments and some information about them.

This is the SQL:

```
SELECT apartment.id, AVG(review.staff), COUNT(distinct review.id), city.name as city_name, state.state as state_name,
    MIN(room.price_per_night)
FROM room
    LEFT JOIN apartment ON room.apartment_id=apartment.id
    LEFT JOIN review ON room.apartment_id=review.apartment_id
    LEFT JOIN city ON apartment.city_id = city.id
    LEFT JOIN state ON city.city_state_id = state.id
GROUP BY apartment.id;
```

which works.

But when I try to turn it to DQL, everything goes fine until I try to join the review table:

```
    $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder('c');

    $qb->select("MIN(r.price_per_night), rev.id")
       ->from("TechforgeApartmentBundle:Room", 'r')
       ->leftJoin('r.apartment', 'a')
       ->leftJoin('Review', 'rev', \Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Join::WITH, 'r.apartment = rev.apartment')
       ->groupBy('a.id');
```

It always complains about Review not being identified before:

> [Semantical Error] line 0, col 116 near 'rev WITH r.apartment': Error:
>   Identification Variable Review used in join path expression but was
>   not defined before.

I tried alot, and nothing seemed to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using raw sql queries:

```
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
        $stmt = $em->getConnection()
                   ->prepare("...
             ");
        $stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure you can leave off the WITH condition, assuming Apartment and Review have a mapped association.

```
$qb->select('MIN(r.price_per_night), rev.id')
   ->from('TechforgeApartmentBundle:Room', 'r')
   ->leftJoin('r.apartment', 'a')
   ->leftJoin('a.review', 'rev')
   ->groupBy('a.id');
```

If for some reason you do need the WITH condition, the syntax looks like this:

```
->leftJoin('a.review', 'rev', 'WITH', 'a.id = rev.apartment_id')
```

Comment: But I don't have an association from apartment to review. Review has the association to apartment.